# How do we set rows(rows) and columns(cols) for an editor?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

How can we set rows(`rows`) and columns(`cols`) for an `Tiny MCE editor` in xml form values.

```
<field name="description"
    type="editor"
    label="COM_USERS_DESCRIPTION_LBL"
    description="COM_USERS_DESCRIPTION_DESC"
    class="inputbox"
    filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
    buttons="true"  
/>
```

If we change editor to the `toogle editor` area, then its looks larger. so we have to fix the cols and rows size for the editor without using the css style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use `Width` for editor in joomla. [Click here](http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type) to know more....

[see also](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types) this one....

Comment: I am asking with the version joomla2.5

Comment: Thanks its working fine. using the `width` and `height` of the params